# Is there a way to search in elasticsearch with nested json?

Tags: elasticsearch

In elastic search data has been saved in below format:

```
{
'name': 'somename',
'data': '{"age": 25}'
}
```

How to search like

```
{"match": {"data.age": 25}}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [nested data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) for your `data` field and then you can use the example given in the same doc to query the nested fields.

In short, you need to include the `nested path` in your query if its indexed properly.

```
"nested": {
      "path": "data",
```

**Adding end to end working example, according to your sample**

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name" : {
                "type" : "text"
            },
            "data": {
                "type": "nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index request**

```
{
    "name": "somename",
    "data": {
        "age": 25
    }
}
```

**search request**

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "data.age": 25
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And search result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "nested",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "somename",
                    "data": {
                        "age": 25
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail. In my case if you will notice the nested object for key `data` is string. `'data': '{"age": 25}'`. If it will be simple object then the example will perfectly work.

Comment: I also upvoted your answer *until* I read your two comments. A bit too desperate to my mind, I must say.

Answer (score 2):

**GET /myIndex/_search**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data",
      "query": {
          {"match": {"data.age": 25}}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks Raghu for the detail. In my case if you will notice the nested object for key `data` is string. `'data': '{"age": 25}'`. If it will be simple object then no issue.

Comment: @cyberminder this is not possible, you should try changing the way you stored your data into the index. BTW why are you putting string instead of an object?

Comment: Graylog saves data in elasticsearch .